# How to specify passphrases for P12 to PEM file conversion without interaction.

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

I'm trying to convert a P12 file to a PEM file. When I execute the command, the terminal asks me for three things:

P12 passphrase (I type it in, hit enter)
PEM passphrase (type it in, hit enter)
PEM passphrase confirm (type it in, hit enter)

I know I can execute a sudo command all in one shot by using the following:

```
echo sudopassword | sudo rm -rf /file.p12;
```

How can I add all three values in one shot? Thanks

Comment: What are you using to convert? openssl?

Comment: If you'd give the actual commands in question, this would be easier.

Comment: Wouldn't this fit better in SuperUser or ServerFault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain what these P12 files are?  I found [this link](http://www.gridsite.org/wiki/Convert_p12) which deals with the conversion of pkcs12 Cert/key files to .PEM format using `openssl`.  (http://gridsite.org)

Key to the answer is:

**Use `-passin file:...` and `-passout file:...` for unattended processing**

It's my guess that you will have to specify the `-passin file:P12passphrase` and `-passout file PEMpassphrase` options for this case.

This little test confirms how an input passphrase can be specified through a `file:<...>` parameter.  This helps to hide such phrases from any *over the shoulder* attacks.  Don't forget to restrict access to such files. Even though it's a common feature of most openssl commands, it's not explicitly mentioned and it is key to the original question.  The full list of options is below.

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -passin file:P12phrase
Can't open file P12phrase
Error getting passwords
```

(I leave it to the OP to construct the full command.)

Below are all supported options for the `pkcs12` subcommand:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 help 
Usage: pkcs12 [options]
where options are
-export       output PKCS12 file
-chain        add certificate chain
-inkey file   private key if not infile
-certfile f   add all certs in f
-CApath arg   - PEM format directory of CA's
-CAfile arg   - PEM format file of CA's
-name "name"  use name as friendly name
-caname "nm"  use nm as CA friendly name (can be used more than once).
-in  infile   input filename
-out outfile  output filename
-noout        don't output anything, just verify.
-nomacver     don't verify MAC.
-nocerts      don't output certificates.
-clcerts      only output client certificates.
-cacerts      only output CA certificates.
-nokeys       don't output private keys.
-info         give info about PKCS#12 structure.
-des          encrypt private keys with DES
-des3         encrypt private keys with triple DES (default)
-aes128, -aes192, -aes256
              encrypt PEM output with cbc aes
-nodes        don't encrypt private keys
-noiter       don't use encryption iteration
-maciter      use MAC iteration
-twopass      separate MAC, encryption passwords
-descert      encrypt PKCS#12 certificates with triple DES (default RC2-40)
-certpbe alg  specify certificate PBE algorithm (default RC2-40)
-keypbe alg   specify private key PBE algorithm (default 3DES)
-keyex        set MS key exchange type
-keysig       set MS key signature type
-password p   set import/export password source
-passin p     input file pass phrase source
-passout p    output file pass phrase source
-engine e     use engine e, possibly a hardware device.
-rand file:file:...
              load the file (or the files in the directory) into
              the random number generator
-CSP name     Microsoft CSP name
-LMK          Add local machine keyset attribute to private key
```

Comment: It was not intended as a demo, but to explain the file:... syntax.  I've removed my original comment and updated the text of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that these commands are reading from stdin. It's more likely that they're reading directly from the terminal. This allows them to set a mode that doesn't echo the password to the screen. Try echoing your input to `/dev/tty`.

Beyond that, you'll need to use something like [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) / [pexect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to control these. Those projects were build specifically for this purpose.

---

Openssl has a -stdin optoin to read its input from stdin. This works:

```
tmp=`mktemp`
cat > $tmp <<EOF                                                                                       







$1                                                                                      

EOF                                                                                     
cat $tmp | openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
```

I've used cat and a here-document to avoid putting the password on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

I used `openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out sampleCore.pem -nodes` and it was working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just echoing three lines? It would probably work

```
echo $'P12 passphrase\nPEM passphrase\nPEM passphrase confirm' | cmd
```

Although I feel I must point out that echoing passwords like this is highly insecure. Not only does the password end up in your bash history file, but it's also visible to anyone else on the system who runs `ps`.

Comment: Nice try, but that isn't working. I'm still prompted for the three passwords.

Comment: @JackHumphries: In that case, the command is probably talking to the tty directly instead of using stdin. Which is a good hint that you shouldn't be trying to do it like this.

Comment: What do you suggest I do then? Surely there's a way to do this. I'm uploading a P12 file to a PHP file (which is why the command has to be in one shot). PHP is then executing this shell command. This is all on my own personal server, and I can call `history -c` after it's done.

Comment: @JackHumphries: Maybe you can write a script to use with `expect`?